# Why do I need a curried function to be able to pass function literals with short placeholder syntax?

Tags: scala

Given this definition:

```
class Foo(var x: String) {}

object Helper {
  def model[T](get: ⇒ T, set: T ⇒ Unit) : Model[T] = new Model[T] {
    override def getObject(): T = get

    override def setObject(obj: T) { set(obj) }
  }
}
```

I try to call `model` like this:

```
val f = new Foo("initial")
val stringModel = model(f.x, f.x = _)
```

But that doesn't work, the compiler gives me this, complaining about the underscore:

```
missing parameter type for expanded function ((x$1) => f.x = x$1)
```

If I change the definition of `model` to use two parameter lists like this:

```
def model[T](get: ⇒ T)(set: T ⇒ Unit) // rest is unchanged
```

Then I can call it like this:

```
model(f.x)(f.x = _)
```

Which I find nice and concise. I don't really mind doing it like this, though it makes method overloading harder. I would like to understand, however, why the second variant works and the first one doesn't?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The second variant works because Scala refines its types parameter-block by parameter-block.  If you don't specify the type of your input parameter for the function, it's possible that it would change the type `T` that it has inferred based on the first parameter.  If you push it to a separate parameter block, Scala's already decided what `T` must be by the time it hits that block, so it fills in the only possible value for the function argument type.

Comment: Ahhh... thanks. That just made a big *click* in my mind. Of course this made me immediately try calling it as `model[String](...)` and lo and behold, of course it works like that. Thank you!